# How to write this nested and multiple conditional branching in a clear way?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

Assume `P1, P2, Q1` and `Q2` are predicates.

I come up with two implementations of the same thing:

```
if (P1(x) ? P2(y) : true) && (Q1(z) ? Q2(w) : true )
    do-something
```

and

```
if (P1(x)  &&  Q1(z) )
    if ( P2(y) && Q2(w) )
        do-something

if (P1(x)  &&  ! Q1(z) )
    if ( P2(y) )
        do-something

if ( ! P1(x)  &&  Q1(z) )
    if ( Q2(w) )
        do-something

if ( ! P1(x)  &&  ! Q1(z) )
    do-something
```

I prefer the first one because it is more concise. But do I miss something?

Is there a  way better than the above two to do the same thing?

If there are more pairs of predicates `R1` and `R2` work similarly to `P1` and `P2`, is the first way a good or the best way?

Is it always better to implement `P2` and `Q2` as functions? What if they are not implemented as functions?

Comment: since this appears to be a question about the possible permutations of **functional** code, it seems to be a better fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

if ((!P1(x) || P2(y)) && (!Q1(z) || Q2(w))) do something

Comment: You're missing a `(`. And is the above really **clear**? That's clearly a subjective assessment.

Comment: which one is more clear?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Obviously, this is a very good way to write the expression as it **clearly** show the logic. Equivalent logic using `if/else` is also acceptable and might be required sometime in practice if for example you would need to compute `y` if you need to call `P2`. And sometime, it could be useful for debugging purpose (easier to set a breakpoint on a particular case) or to make the code easier to read if the expression is very long...